# Solving multi DOF damped system using block matrix and matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, multilinear-algebra, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to solve a multi DOF damped system for $U$. $[M]$ and $[K]$ are symmetric nxn matrices, but $[C]$ is not symmetric. Can I use the following approach?

1. Put in block matrix form
2. Solve the 1st order differential using exponential matrices

Is it true that because $[C]$ is not symmetrical then it can't have distinct eigenvalues/eigenvectors, making it not possible to diagonalize? But even if that's true, $e^{[A]t}$ can still be found without diagonalizing, right?

[image: working]

Comment: Is $[M]$ always invertible?

Comment: yes, [M] is always invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. By differentiating the candidate $X(t)$ we recover the correct differential equation.

A non-symmetric matrix can have distinct eigenvectors/ eigenvalues. Example
$$M= \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)$$
Is not symmetric but has the following eigensystem
$$\lambda_1=1, u_1=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\lambda_2=2, u_2=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$

There are many ways to compute the matrix exponential. The one you suggest is perfectly fine. The most direct is by using the power series of the exponential$^\dagger$

$$e^{At}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n t^n}{n!}$$

Which is useful if your matrix has some nice property of powers, eg if $A^2=1$. A different useful method is via the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#Matrix_functions), for which you'll only need the eigenvalues. There's a worked example using this on the wiki page.

$\dagger$ Also useful because this definition of the matrix exponential is always well defined (the sum converges).

Answer to question in comment: *"why is the damping approximated?"*
I can't comment on the engineering textbooks, but I assume the approximation is done in order to get a (set of) linear differential equations, which can then be cast into matrix form. Things are not so simple if your damping term is eg $ u\dot{u}$, the resulting equation is nonlinear and all the nice things done above won't work: the solution can't simply be cast into matrix form. The approximation could also be done to render your matrix $A$ time independent. If $A$ is time dependent (and the differential equations are linear), the method you described won't directly work, but the solution may still be cast in matrix form (see eg. A. Prosperetti: *Advanced mathematics*, ch18)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) So, even though [C] can have distinct eigenvalues/vectors, in general, it won't. However, this isn't a problem because there are other ways to calculate $e^{[A]t}$, so an exact solution can be found. I have one weird quick follow up question:

Why does every Engineering vibration book make such a big deal about trying to approximate [C] by assuming small damping or assuming Rayleigh damping ($[C] = \alpha [M] + \beta [K]$)? If it can be solved exactly, why bother approximating an answer? Numerical efficiency?

Comment: No problem! My reply was too long for a comment, so I've edited my answer to include the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the diff eqns are still linear regardless of whether [C] is symmetric or not. As long as [C] consists of constants like [M] and [K] do then the equation should be linear.

Comment: I've been pondering this for a while, and I think from an engineering perspective, damping may be unknown (or very hard to measure) so that's why engineers approximate [C] - if you're going to invent a [C] that fits data, you might as well make it easy to deal with numerically.

Comment: Yes, my first answer was to the question: "why is damping approximated?", which wasn't the question you asked. You're correct, once in matrix form, the equations are of course linear.